# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed " ASP.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to dependency inject a service into another service but I can't make it work and after some searches around the internet I can't see a solution to it yet...

This is the exact error:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyBank.Services.ITransactionService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: MyBank.Services.TransactionService': Unable to resolve service for type 'MyBank.Services.AccountsService' while attempting to activate 'MyBank.Services.TransactionService'.)'

I have this service:

```
public class AccountsService : IAccountsService
```

And I want to inject it into another service:

```
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService
{
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        private readonly AccountsService accountsService;

        public TransactionService(ApplicationDbContext db, AccountsService accountsService)
        {
            this.db = db;
            this.accountsService = accountsService;
        }
}
```

And this is my Startup.cs Service area:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            _ = services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddRazorPages().
                AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();         
            services.AddScoped<IAccountsService, AccountsService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransactionService, TransactionService>();
        }
```

Comment: A service starts with no Environmental variables using System Account.  I think you want to create a user account for the service which has the proper environment and then start the service with the user account privileges.  See : https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-start-service-specific-user-account-windows-server-2016?force_isolation=true

Comment: The account service can be any other service, I am using it to update some raw data from Accounts table, it is not related to "user-like" structure

Comment: How can service read your configuration?  Does it have the privileges to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inject `AccountsService` (the implementation), not `IAccountsService` (the interface) into `TransactionService`.